# Graph Monomorphism Algorithms in Java (VF2/Ambiguous Terminology)

Tags: java, graph, graph-algorithm, isomorphism

Looking for an implementation of VF2 in Java that can determine if a directed acyclic graph G1 is isomorphic to a subgraph (not necessarily an induced subgraph) of a directed graph G2. I believe within the context of the graph isomorphism problem the correct term is monomorphism. Any algorithm needs to also return mapping between vertices that creates the monomorphism.

Formally let H = (VH, EH) and G = (V, E) be digraphs. Does there exists a function f : VH → V such that if (u, v) ∈ EH, then (f(u), f(v)) ∈ E.

And if it does not exist in java, will VFLib in c++ do what I need. (I strongly believe it should but terminology has thrown me for a loop and I would love confirmation for someone who really understands what they are talking about before re-doing everything I have in c++.)

There are a number of recommendations on similar questions notably S-Space https://github.com/fozziethebeat/S-Space
However S-Space refers only to graph isomorphism not subgraph isomorphism/monomorphism. Attempting to read the code at 
https://github.com/fozziethebeat/S-Space/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/ucla/sspace/graph/isomorphism/VF2State.java found the lines:

```
/**
 * The number of nodes in {@code g1}
 */
private final int n1;

/**
 * The number of nodes in {@code g2}
 */
private final int n2;

public boolean isDead() {
    return n1 != n2 
        || t1bothLen != t2bothLen
        || t1outLen != t2outLen
        || t1inLen != t2inLen;        
}
```

Which seems to indicate that it will only work for graph isomorphisms (as graphs with different numbers of nodes will be rejected). But I am a LONG way from really having a feel for the code.

Apart from VFLib  and networkx (python and doesnt support monomorphism) I havent been able to tell which of the three VF2 options (isomorphism, subgraph isomorphism, monomorphism) a given implimentation supports.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: What solution did you use, @Fishy314?